# I can't predict a single image using keras

Tags: keras

Im trying to predict a single image using keras. but the model isn't taking the image. this is the code i used:

```python
x = cv2.imread('download.png')
x=cv2.resize(x,(150,150))
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)
pred = model.predict_classes(x)
print(pred)
```

this is the error i get:

> expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape
>   (1, 150, 150, 3)

```python
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(num_pixels, input_dim=num_pixels, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Comment: you do not even show the model. The input layer on the mode you are using is not formatted to take RGB images but is instead expecting a single flat vector. Please provide the model architecture and we can actually help.

Comment: sorry, i just updated the question with the model

Comment: did you just accept the answer, then un-accept it and downvote it? really?

Comment: i'm sorry, it just didn't answer the question, if you edit ur answer, i can remove the downvote. the issue i'm having right now, is that I need to predict the image but the image is not the right size.

Comment: no that is not your issue. Read the error message. When declaring your model, the shape of the input is not just num_pixels. It is a 4D array of shape (samples, height, width, channels). Thus, your network needs to be changed. What do you not understand.

Comment: sorry just edit u answer so i can upvote

Answer (score 0):

Your input, for RGB images, should be something along these lines:

```
shape = (IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3)  # height, width, depth

input_layer = Input(shape=shape)
```

you can then choose to flatten the input, and pass it through your simple feed forward network.

```
flatten = Flatten()(input_layer)
dense = Dense(num_pixels, activation='relu')
dense = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')

model = Model(input_layer, dense)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

(not this is using the keras functional API). You will need to:

```
from keras.models import Model
```

However, I do not think the above model will really work for any task too well. Maybe use a relatively simple [CNN](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/):

```
input_layer = Input(shape=shape)

# Block 1
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='block1_conv1')(input_layer)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='block1_conv2')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool')(x)

# Block 2
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='block2_conv1')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='block2_conv2')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block2_pool')(x)

# Block 3
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='block3_conv1')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='block3_conv2')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool')(x)

# Block 4
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='block4_conv1')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='block4_conv2')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block4_pool')(x)

# Block 5
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='block5_conv1')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='block5_conv2')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block5_pool')(x)

# Classification block
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
x = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='pred')(x)

model = Model(input_layer, x)
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```